# Is there a kanji for panther?

Tags: kanji, animals

I’ve been looking for it and haven’t found a clear answer, for example “豹” appears as panther in some pages but in others that translates to leopard, I’ve also seen “豹属” as panther

Comment: Panther is a word that doesn't even have a very precise meaning in colloquial English either. Many big cats (and many of which are not native to Asia) are called panthers.

Comment: Is it the same thing as the mountain lion?

Comment: @aguijonazo:  I've never heard mountain lions referred to as "panthers", but a quick Google search suggests they can be.

Answer (score 2):

A short answer is that you could use 豹 if you mean the animal with round spots on its skin.

---

[A dictionary](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=panther) says that *leopard* and *panther* are synonymous while [this website](https://pediaa.com/difference-between-panther-and-leopard/) claims that panthers are black(ish).

In Japanese, 豹 is a species under the genus [豹属](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%92%E3%83%A7%E3%82%A6%E5%B1%9E). Normally 豹 makes us think of spotted yellow skin (e.g. ヒョウ柄) and there is a specific word 黒豹 to refer to black leopards/panthers. So as a name of the species, 豹 corresponds to the  English *[leopard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leopard)*.  If you mean black leopards by *panther*, then there is no common single kanji for it.